# Как задать параметры располажения элементов для каждого типа устройств?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Я создаю приложение. Тестировал приложение на одном устройстве. Но недавно, я перешёл на планшет, где размер экрана совсем другой и из-за этого элементы разбросаны. На втором фото элемент текста находиться посредине, а вот на первом в левом краю. Я его закрепил (для первого фото), но на втором оно не знает, как мне можно закрепить элементы так, что бы можно было адекватно смотреть на элементы (значение match-perent делает элемент на элементе (я не понимаю что делать с даным значением))

P.s. Редактирую месторасполажения с редактора, то есть не использую код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо имеет смысл почитать мануалы про созданию разметки и о том какие параметры как на не влияют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь разметкой LinearLayout и задайте значения с помощю

```
android:gravity
```